# Sharepoint: Person column in custom list

Tags: sharepoint

I have a Person field in my custom list.  I want to have a view that will show multiple fields from that Person instead of the one I had to choose when creating the Person column.

So basically I want to have one column for Person and then in the view see Name, title, email, phone.  All of those are valid choices but I can only pick one right now.

I really want to avoid typing in the username lookup for each column I choose to display.

This is SP 2007

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to create a custom fieldtype (with a fieldcontrol) that inherits from the userfield but in viewmode renders out the different columns you need. Is that something along the lines you are looking for?

http://www.sharepointblogs.com/nicksevens/archive/2007/08/31/create-custom-field-types-for-sharepoint.aspx

Note: This link is broken

Comment: Unfortunately, the out of the box calculated field does not allow you to pick from a Person or Group field, so this is the best way.

Comment: It looks like this is going to be my cleanest approach.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want a Computed Field.  Note that this is not a Calculated Column.  A Computed Field is what is used to display the same data is different ways.  In SharePoint there is a Title field, but there is also a "Title (linked to item with edit menu)" computed field as well as a "Title (linked to item)" computed field.

See midway down [this link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointdesigner/HA102390461033.aspx) for more details.  I'm not sure if it will have all of the power that you need, but if it does it is almost certainly what you are looking for if you don't mind getting into the Schema XML file a little.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use a DataView web part for this? If it's just a question of viewing the data that might be suitable.

Answer (score 0):

Came across this thread and thought I'd add a tip.  This suggestion is clearly not for every use case, but may work well in situations where you're managing a list rather than allowing manual inputs (verified to work with SP 2013):

1. Create a spreadsheet with columns to match your SharePoint list that contains multiple profile fields. (for example: name, phone number, email address)
2. In the spreadsheet, enter the **same** email address in all of the person/group field types in that row. (e.g., boss@company.com, boss@company.com, boss@company.com)
3. Select and copy the row(s) you wish to transfer to SharePoint.
4. In SharePoint, change the list view to "Quick Edit" and paste the row(s) into the grid.
5. SharePoint will process each field and convert the email address to the profile value you selected during the list setup.